# Reverse default sort order for 'tag' search (on a user)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search, tag-search

When I go to my user page and click on one of the tags, I get a search result for all questions/answers I've written for that tag. But they're sorted "oldest first" by default.

Example: [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:291741+[java]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:291741+%5Bjava%5D)

The tab that's selected by default is "relevance", and I don't think, that the oldest questions are most relevant - are they?

I don't like that default very much, because if someone searches for the answers/questions of a user about a specific tag (which a potential employer might want to do for example), they primarily find their very first posts - which are often not as good as they could be...

So I would recommend to either reverse the sort order, or to set the "newest" tab as default.

Comment: Technically they are sorted by relevance.  But it seems there may be something wrong with the sorting.